# Script to add a driver to "hide" a bone

Tags: scripting, bones, drivers

I'm tryng to write a script that adds a driver to some bones automatically. But I'm facing some problems with the property "hide".
I want to add the driver into the property "Hide" (Inside Viewport display of a bone). All the rest of the code seems to be working correctly.

[image]

This is my code:

```
import bpy

# Set the name of the armature and list of bones
armature_name = "RIG-Luana"
bone_names = [
    "STR-shorts_bot_tweak1.L",
    "STR-shorts_bot_tweak2.L",
    "STR-shorts_bot_tweak3.L",
    "STR-shorts_bot_tweak4.L",
    "STR-shorts_bot_tweak1.R",
    "STR-shorts_bot_tweak2.R",
    "STR-shorts_bot_tweak3.R",
    "STR-shorts_bot_tweak4.R"
]

# Set up the driver expression
driver_expression = 'roupa != 0'

# Loop through each bone name and apply the driver
for bone_name in bone_names:
    bone = bpy.data.objects[armature_name].pose.bones[bone_name]
    
    # Add the driver
    driver = bone.driver_add("hide").driver
    
    # Add the variable to the driver
    var = driver.variables.new()
    var.name = "roupa"
    var.targets[0].id_type = 'OBJECT'
    var.targets[0].id = bpy.data.objects[armature_name]
    var.targets[0].data_path = 'pose.bones["Properties_Character_Luana"]["Roupa"]'
    
    # Set up the driver type and expression
    driver.type = 'SCRIPTED'
    driver.expression = driver_expression
```

First I made a test adding the driver to the property of the scale of the object, and it works. But I don't know how to acess the property "hide" of the bone. Any ideia how to fix the code? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It's in the "how odd" category ....

Although The Viewport Display "Hide" property doesn't show when you are in Edit mode (implying bones instead of pose-bones), the property is actually accessible via the Edit mode (object.data.bones), so use the interface:

```
for bone in bpy.data.objects['metarig'].data.bones:
    driver = bone.driver_add("hide").driver
```